# Scatter Plot issue for alignment

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core plot into my project and i am creating scatter plot and i am enabling user interaction to yes.
But issue is plot display in center value of x-axis and i want to see plot in starting from Axes.

I am using following code for making space between major ticks but when its seen into center position and after scrolling i will go to first point.

I want to first see first point and after scrolling another points.

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.5)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
```

I am stuck with this issue.

I am posting screen shot of this issue.
Here i am uploading two images
1) Chart shows into center.
2) I want to show chart like this on startup.

Issue Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Awe.png)

Second Image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBmML.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the pictures you provided, I suppose you want to be sure that the vertical axis is always shown. You can achieve that with

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft += 60.0; // to make some room for the axis
```

If you just want the first point to be shown, try this

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [[plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
xRange.location = CPTDecimalFromDouble(yourFirstDataPoint.x);  // insert your data her
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Here in second code what is yourFirstDatapoint.x value? Using your first code Vertical axis shows but value of x-axis is shows into center value of xrange.

Comment: This is the x value of your leftmost data point. The one you want to be shown in the graph. I don't know how your data is named, so please adjust this to your case.

Comment: I am already set this value for spacing between two x values. CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
 [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.5)];
 plotSpace.xRange = xRange;  But it did not work to show first x value into screen after scrolling i shows first value.

Comment: You set this value differently. `expandRangeByFactor` scales the plotRange and keeps the center of the range the same. For example, if your plot range was 0 to 10, scaling by 0.5 means you get a range from 2.5 to 7.5. So the both ends of your plot are out of sight.

Comment: Yes its true and my value range is 1 to 30 so its shows 15 value. So what to do to expand range and see starting point.

Comment: Do both: `[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.5)];` and then `xRange.location = CPTDecimalFromDouble(2.0);`